# Is any way to get relations for all order if is polymorphic?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have an Order model, Product and SerialsNo. You can have order ID and list of products and one to many serialNo.

Order

```
public function products() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'order_id', 'id');
}
```

Product

```
public function serialNumbers() {
    return $this->morphMany('App\SerialNumber', 'serial_numberable');
}
```

SerialNumber

```
public function serial_numberable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

if i would like get serial numbers for products

```
$sn = Product::find(1); 
dd($sn->serialNumbers);
```

how can i get serials numbers in 
`dd($order->products())` 
collections ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a collection of products with their `serialnumbers` you can do:

```
dd($order->products->load('serialNumbers'));
```

If you only want a collection of the `serialnumbers` you can do:

```
dd($order->products->load('serialNumbers')->pluck('serialNumbers'));
```